# Detect fingerprint sensor event without local authentication

Tags: ios, iphone, fingerprint

in iOS is there any way to detect fingerprint sensor event without local authentication and without registering fingerprint ?

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: @Paulw11 I know there is way but I dont know how we can do that..

Comment: Why do you say you know there is a way?  There is no access to the touchID hardware available to iOS apps except via the local authentication framework.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have seen one enterprise app which is doing this same thing..

Comment: Ah, well, Enterprise apps don't go through Apple review, so they can use private APIs, but you can't do that if you want to target the app store.  Even then I would be surprised if there is even a private API for such things since TouchID hardware access is accessed outside of the app process space.